# Non-Access or -base QBE tool?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I'm currently looking for a QBE tool that can execute
queries on PostgreSQL or MySQL.

OS doesn't really matter.

Reason is that we've got to do QBE at school but I don't want to use neither Microsoft Access nor OpenOffice.org Base (lack of features).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you include as tags the programs you've eliminated from consideration? I wouldn't be reading your answer without the ms-access tag, and I can't help you with any alternatives, so the tag has wasted my time by causing a question to pop up that I have nothing to offer on.

Comment: So what?
Don't be so egoistical, enjoy your life.

Comment: Do you want help or not? You can mention the ones you've eliminated from consideration in your question, but you really shouldn't have them in the tags. In fact, I'm removing the inapplicable tags now.

Answer (score 0):

I find the MS Access works quite well as a front-end for MySQL when a 'quick' front-end is needed.  For something more robust I would recommend HeidiSQL.